# Differenct Findbugs behavior with QAPlug-findbugs and gradle configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, findbugs, build.gradle

I am working on a Java project. I am using IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4 as IDE.

I verify the quality of code two ways,

- I have installed QAPlug-FindBugs plugin in IntelliJ idea and I analyze the code using
  a custom analysis profile. This profile has only one findbugs rule activated.
- I have applied findbugs plugin in build.gradle file of the project. I
  run gradlew check command.

These two approaches result into different number of findbugs warnings/errors. Actually, gradlew check results into lot more errors/warnings than QAPlug -> Analyze Code.

I understand that when I mention apply plugin : 'findbugs' the effort level is set to Default value.

I tried to figure out the relation between gradle plugin and Intellij Idea plugin. I am not able to figure out what coding rules should be activated in my custom profile (for QAPlug -> Analyze Code action) to match the behavior of 'gradle check'.

Can anybody give me a pointer as to what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Vijay,

I am not sure if you are looking for information about QAPlug or Gradle.
In case of QAPlug please check following tutorial:

- [Creating your own analysis profile](https://qaplug.com/tutorial/#tutorial2)

Regarding the Gradle, I found the following information: 
"By default, all detectors which are not disabled by default are run."
[Gradle FindBugsExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html)

To have the same number of Findbugs warnings/errors you should do the following:

- deactivate all rules in you custom QAPlug analysis profile
- using search box find those "Powered by Findbugs" and activate them

I hope that it helps.